# How to include a component of Winform to project by programatically?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I created Windows Form in Visual Studio 2013 which WinForm  compound with three files.

1. frm.vb
2. frm.Designer.vb
3. frm.resx

I try to use this code for include them to my project

```
  Private Sub IncludeFileToProjectVS(ByVal screenComp As ScreenComponent)    
    Dim process As New Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(My.Settings.Path_project)
    process.AddItem("Compile", "D:\MyProject\Forms\frm.vb")
    process.AddItem("Compile", "D:\MyProject\Forms\frm.Designer.vb")
    process.AddItem("Compile", "D:\MyProject\Forms\frm.resx")
    process.Save()
End Sub
```

But It is not correct becuase they was include in the same level. 
How to include .Designer.vb and .resx into the frm.vb like these

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the sub-items need the `DependentUpon` metadata set to the identity of the `frm.vb` item (the full path to `frm.vb` in your case I guess).
(Plus, I guess the `resx` file needs to be an `EmbeddedResource` instead of `Compile`? you might want to look this up in an existing/working vbproj file).

Comment: Did you mean  XML file? What possilble if i add dependentupun tag via vb.

Comment: The `DependentUpon` makes the solution explorer display the hierarchy